# Differential function

Tags: calculus

Let $f: A \cup B\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be differentible where $A=\{(x,y):\frac{1}{2}<x^2+y^2<1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y):(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2<\frac{1}{2}\}$
Let Df be the derivative of the function of the  following  necessarily correct ?

1.If (Df)(x,y)=o for all $(x,y)\in A \cup B$ then f is constant.

2.If (Df)(x,y)=o for all $(x,y)\in A $ then f is constant on A.

3.If (Df)(x,y)=o for all $(x,y)\in B $ then f is constant on B.

4. If (Df)(x,y)=o for all $(x,y)\in A \cup B $ then for some $(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1)\in \mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)$ for all $(x,y)\in A$ and $f(x,y)=(x_1,y_1)$ for all $(x,y)\in B$

I can not understand how to deal with the given region .

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that as long as the derivative vanishes on a *connected* set, the function is constant over that set (hint: if $\Omega \neq \varnothing$ is an open connected and $f: \Omega \subset \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is such that $Df(x) = 0$ for all $x\in \Omega$, fix $a \in \Omega$ and consider $A:=\{ x\in \Omega: f(x) = f(a)\}$. It is nonempty and clopen [hint: MVT on a ball around $a$], so it must be $=\Omega$).

Now as $A$ and $B$ are connected, all of $2,3$ and $4$ are correct. You can easily construct a counterexample to $1$.